# "unwilling" vs. "refuse"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

Suppose Sam is a kind of person who always follows his own will when it comes to taking actions.

In this case, are the two sentences below identical in meaning?

> Sam is refusing to make it happen.
>
> Sam is unwilling to make it happen.

Comment: I can be *unwilling* to jump off a bridge, but you can't say I *refuse* to jump off a bridge unless someone has asked or commanded me to.

Comment: _(Un)willing_ is a state of mind; _refusing_ is a performative speech act. Big difference.

Comment: @JohnLawler One can *refuse* without speaking. I know I have.

Comment: It's still performative; pragmatics includes non-speech events.

Comment: @JohnLawler But does a performative involve actions that don't include speaking? I thought performatives were actions where the speaking was a de facto doing of the speech act described by the verb you're using as you actually say *hat veb*. As in *I declare you man and wife* kind of thing ...

Comment: That's one kind; but if you shake your head when they tell you what to do, instead of doing it, then you've performed the communicative act of refusing.

Comment: @Araucaria If someone tells you to come to them, and you turn and walk in the other direction, you're clearly refusing to do what they asked.

Comment: I could say "I refuse to read romance novels"... but that doesn't require that someone's told me I must.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unwilling doesn't necessarily mean that you didn't do something, but refusal suggests so.

An example Google gives as part of its definition is "unwilling conscripts".

Being unwilling to serve in the army could mean you grumble while you're there, whereas refusing to serve in the army implies you'll be thrown in prison.